# javascript toggle in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, toggle

I am creating a small extension just to add simple styles to current tab

```
// Called when the user clicks on the browser action.
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  // No tabs or host permissions needed!
  chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    code: "var flag; console.log(flag); if(flag !== 1){window.document.styleSheets[0].insertRule('html{font-size: 10px;}'); flag = 1} else{window.document.styleSheets[0].removeRule('html{font-size: 16px;}'); flag = 0;}"
  });
});
```

which works fine, And to create a *toggle* I wrote this logic:

```
var flag;
console.log(flag);
if (flag !== 1) {
  window.document.styleSheets[0].insertRule('html{font-size: 10px;}');
  flag = 1
} else {
  window.document.styleSheets[0].removeRule('html{font-size: 16px;}');
  flag = 0;
}
```

When clicking the button first time, flag value is *undefined*.

**My question:** Is there any better way to write this toggle?

Comment: you log the value to the console to soon. So first do the toggle, and then console.log the value. It should be set

Comment: You littary said the value was undefined the first time.

Comment: Yes, the value will be undefined because of `var flag;` using console.log does not improve the toggle approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to achieve what you are trying to do, could be done using Chrome's [Tabs API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs) and [Storage API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage#property-sync)

```
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function(tab) {        
    chrome.storage.get({"bhansa": "NOT_FOUND"}, function(store){
       var bhansa = false;
       if (store["bhansa"] || store["bhansa"] == "NOT_FOUND") {
           bhansa = true;
           chrome.storage.set({"bhansa": !bhansa});
       }
       if (bhansa) {
          chrome.tabs.insertCss(tab.id , {code : "html.... " } ,
              function() {
                  console.log("Done adding styles."); 
              }
          );
       }
    }            
});
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I guess its better to use `"NOT_FOUND"` instead undefined.

Answer (score 1):

executeScript is misleading - it **inserts** the script into the page and runs it, it doesn't just execute that code on the page. So you'll be inserting multiple copies of the script. It's hard to say what the page will do with multiple copies of your script, it should at least complain that flag is already defined.

However, if you accept multiple copies might get inserted but it won't particularly matter, then you should do this so that the flag state is predictable:

```
window.flag = window.flag || false;
flag = !flag; // toggle - note window scope is implicit
if (flag) {
    // do flag == true stuff
} else {
    // do flag == false stuff
}
```

By explicitly referring to the window object, you can add a property without needing to declare it and it will default to false. It also doesn't matter how many times that line is executed.

It is generally considered bad practice to add more than one variable to the window object and you should name it something that will never clash with any other variable - i.e. not flag!
Having said that, it's common practice to create one unique variable to act as a namespace, e.g.

```
window.bhansa = window.bhansa || {myFlag: false, myOtherVariable: 12345};
```

Then bhansa will be created if it doesn't exist and you can safely define functions and add variables as properties of that object without worrying about clashes:

```
bhansa.myFunction = function() {
}
bhansa.myFilename = "xxx"
```